# Android JSONObject always returns "null"

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse JSON from my web server. Fetching data isn't the problem but when I try to create a `JSONObject` it always returns `null`.

My JSON:

```
{"apikey":"c34750f19843vo45239o","error":false}
```

And my Java:

```java
private class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        JSONResult = null;
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        sh.HTTPMethod = DefaultMethod;

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ApiUrl+tmpUrl);

        System.out.println("Response from "+ApiUrl+tmpUrl+": " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONResult = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get json from server.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        clearRequest();
    }

}
```

I have tried with `jsonStr.toString()` but same result. I can also log my JSON string in Java but it isn't parsed.

This is where it returns `null`:

```java
if(JSONResult != null && JSONResult.has("apikey")) {
    ApiKey = JSONResult.getString("apikey");
    System.out.println("Successfully got ApiKey: "+ApiKey);
}else{
    if(JSONResult == null){System.out.println("Is Null");}
}
```

Sorry for my bad English. Hope you understand :)

Comment: What is your response?

Comment: First try to log your response from web server maybe you have a problem with connection or smth

Comment: @A_J I have logged the response.. All fine there

Comment: if your servver response format is erroneous, you will get parsing error, which will lead to json object being null

Comment: @NirupIyer Im doing the Ouput via PHP `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and then I output my JSON via echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing, since you did not show enough of your code.

Most likely you check the result before it has been received. The `AsyncTask` runs asynchronously to your main thread and you would have to wait until it is finished before you can use the result.

In fact, that's the reason why there is an `onPostExecute` method. This is the correct place to process the result.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks :) Is it possible to check from outside the class if it has finished? Something like the onClickListener?

Comment: No, not directly. It is not what you really want. Waiting for the `AsyncTask` to finish would again block the main thread, something you want to avoid. Use the `onPostExecute` method to process the result.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize  JSONObject JSONResult = null;
in your doInBackground method

```
   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        JSONObject JSONResult = null;
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        sh.HTTPMethod = DefaultMethod;

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ApiUrl+tmpUrl);

        System.out.println("Response from "+ApiUrl+tmpUrl+": " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONResult = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get json from server.");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Try this

Comment: Im initializing it outside of the AssyncTask... Do i have to initialize it inside?

Comment: If you initialize global then fine no problem.